# uploading to S3 bucket from Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi have the S3 bucket library in the codeigniter and I'm try to upload a file from a folder but it give me error. Much appreciated if some one could point out what I'm doing worng.

In the Module folder below code.

```
  $this->load->library('s3');
  $bucket = "xxxxxxxxxx";
  $file = "http://localhost/xxxx/backup/01.txt";
  $this->s3->putObjectFile($file, $bucket, 'test', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

I get the below error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: User Warning
Message: S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: http://localhost/xxxx/backup/01.txt
Filename: libraries/S3.php
Line Number: 310
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [inputFile](https://github.com/psugand/CodeIgniter-S3/blob/master/libraries/S3.php#L299-L316) method, its been used by putObjectFile. This checks whether a file or directory exists but you're using an url.

```
public static function inputFile($file, $md5sum = true)
{
    if (!file_exists($file) || !is_file($file) || !is_readable($file))
    {
        trigger_error('S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: ' . $file, E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    return array('file' => $file, 'size' => filesize($file),
        'md5sum' => $md5sum !== false ? (is_string($md5sum) ? $md5sum :
                        base64_encode(md5_file($file, true))) : '');
}
```

Is this a file on your server? Just add the path of your file:

```
$this->load->library('s3');
$bucket = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$file = "/filesystem/backup/01.txt";
$this->s3->putObjectFile($file, $bucket, 'test', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

Comment: IIuisi..I was testing  the code on XAMPP and when I moved it to the server the my code worked. S3 library was just fine, issue was on the file path. I put the full path on the server but for some reason all the paths I tried failed on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can use remote files for putObjectFile. You will have to download your remote file first.